# Js event leaving page and returning

Tags: javascript

I am looking to have an event when a user leaves a page and then returns. The use case is the user is on a page and is needs to leave to install some software. They when they are done, they return to the original page. I need to know when the user returns so the page can check for the install and then forward to another page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `load`/`unload` or `ready` event and `localStorage` to save state for your case.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    if(localStorage.getItem("installing") === "true"){
       localStorage.setItem("installed", true);
       window.location.href = "/redirect-page";
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    if(localStorage.getItem("installing") === "true"){
       localStorage.setItem("installed", true);
       window.location.href = "/redirect-page";
    }
});

$(window).unload(function() {
     localStorage.setItem("installing", true);
});
```

Javascript version:

```
window.load = function(e) {
    if(localStorage.getItem("installing") === "true"){
       localStorage.setItem("installed", true);
       window.location.href = "/redirect-page";
    }
};

window.unload =function() {
     localStorage.setItem("installing", true);
};
```

Comment: Thank you. Which event is triggered when they return to the page?  Or maybe a better way to ask is how does “installed” get triggered? I just need a simple way to know that the user left the page and then do the check once they return to the same page. Thanks so much!

Comment: it will trigger load / ready event (use can use only one of them)